# Algorithm to find the fewest number of values (from a set of values) where the sum equals a value (+ one more condition)

Tags: algorithms, math

The simplest way to explain this is with an example.

You're given then number `19` and you have a set of numbers to choose from: `1, 2, 3, 4, 6`

When choosing values from the list (which can be duplicates), the smallest number of values that adds up to `19` is `4`:

`6, 6, 6, 1`

`6, 6, 4, 3`

Now the list of numbers I want to select is `6, 6, 4, 3` because when plotted on a graph, it draws a smoother gradient going from larger numbers to smaller numbers. `6, 6, 6, 1` is a sudden drop as it goes from the final `6` to the `1`.

I may be wrong (and please correct me if so) but I think a better way of expressing that desire is to choose the list where the product of each of the numbers is the largest value.

`6 * 6 * 6 * 1 = 216`

`6 * 6 * 4 * 3 = 432 (choose this list)`

Another example is choosing `4, 3` instead of `6, 1` for a value of `7`.

How could this be calculated using an algorithm (ideally non-brute-force!) for use with any total value and an arbitrary set of numbers to choose from?

Answer (score 3):

This is the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  The subset sum problem is NP-complete.  In general the solution requires an exhaustive search, so the run time complexity is O(2^N) where N is the number of values in the set.  Alternatively, if the desired sum S is small, dynamic programming can be used with a run time complexity of O(NS).